# VBA: Having two captions in label

Tags: excel, vba, label, userform

I'm trying to create a simple calculator that shows the result of the calculations in a simple userform based on what the user enter in specific cells.

I'm using the

```
x.caption = Range("X").value
```

to display the value calculated.

So far so good, everything works.

I want also the label to show the corresponding unit for each field, say Kg. I tried adding:

```
And x.caption = "Kg"
```

to give:

```
x.caption = Range("X").value And x.caption = "Kg"
```

, but it neither gives me an error or actually works. How does one actually go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation in VB is done with the "&" operator.

E.g.

```
    x.caption = Range("X1").value & " Kg"
```

Comment: Also... `Range("X")` seems odd... You probably mean `Range("X1")` or something?

Comment: You can edit that in the answer `Range("X")` is going to throw error for sure unless it's a named range.

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Yes, X = XX (Column & row). I fused them both, should have said that.